# How do I change my emoji on Sierra

Tags: mac, windows, macos, emoji

How do I change the image of different types of emoji on a Mac, I like the Windows emoji. Can anyone tell me if I can edit the Mac's emoji's to look like the ones on Windows.

Comment: I meant microsoft windows 10 Emojis

Answer (score 1):

You just have to replace the Apple Color Emoji font with another one that uses the Windows glyphs instead of Apple's.  It would presumably have to use Apple's sbix format to work.  I don't know if any such thing exists. You might have to use a Font Editor like FontLab to make one.

Note that emoji you send via email, etc. will always be seen using the font on the receiving machine, regardless of how they look to you.

Comment: Can you help me to get the emoji's replaced.?

Comment: @Peter Sorry, no, it's a huge endeavor with no value.

Comment: Can you at least try and help me make the emoji's black and white, Or make a video and let me see it. Thx

Comment: @Peter Try a google search for "open source emoji font".  I think there are a couple black/white ones already available, they can normally be used on any platform and are much easier to make.